# PySpark: Aggregate function on a column with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark dataframes A and B

```
A
GROUP |    date    | 
 1    | 2021-02-01 |
 1    | 2021-04-01 |
 1    | 2021-07-23 | 
 1    | 2021-07-30 | 
 2    | 2021-02-01 |
 2    | 2021-04-01 |
 2    | 2021-07-23 | 
 2    | 2021-07-30 | 


B
GROUP |    date    | val
 1    | 2021-03-31 | 15
 2    | 2021-03-31 | 25
 2    | 2021-06-30 | 40
```

I want to join them such that the new column `last_reported_val` is (MAX(B.date) and B.date <= A.date and A.group = B.group) or NULL otherwise. The column `val` should take on the corresponding value from `B`. Below is an example:

```
GROUP |    date    | last_reported_val |   val   |
 1    | 2021-02-01 |        NULL       |   NULL  |
 1    | 2021-04-01 |      2021-03-31   |   15    |
 1    | 2021-07-23 |      2021-03-31   |   15    |
 1    | 2021-07-30 |      2021-03-31   |   15    |
 2    | 2021-02-01 |        NULL       |   NULL  |
 2    | 2021-04-01 |      2021-03-31   |   25    |
 2    | 2021-07-23 |      2021-06-30   |   40    |
 2    | 2021-07-30 |      2021-06-30   |   40    |
```

With SQL, I'd do something like

```
SELECT A.group, A.date, (select MAX(B.date) from B where B.date <= A.date and A.group = B.group) as last_reported_val, B.val
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
on A.group = B.group
```

How would you do this in PySpark? I've tried `join` followed by `map` with no success

```
A.join(B, A['GROUP'] == B['GROUP'], 'left')

...

# This raises _thread.lock error 

A.rdd.map(lambda r: (..., A.filter(
    (A['a.date'] == r['a.date']) & (A['group'] == r['group'])
).agg(max_('b.date')).collect())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first join on your condition, then for each date in B which satisfies the condition for more than 1 date in A, take the max date in B by creating a window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

o = (A.alias("A").join(B.alias("B"),on=[F.col("A.GROUP")==F.col("B.GROUP"),
                                  F.col("B.date") <= F.col("A.date")]
                                , how='left')
.select("A.*",F.col("B.date").alias("last_reported_val"),"B.val"))

w = W.partitionBy("GROUP","date").orderBy(F.desc("last_reported_val"))

o.withColumn("Rnum",F.row_number().over(w)).filter("Rnum==1").drop("Rnum").show()
```

---

```
+-----+----------+-----------------+----+
|GROUP|      date|last_reported_val| val|
+-----+----------+-----------------+----+
|    1|2021-02-01|             null|null|
|    1|2021-04-01|       2021-03-31|  15|
|    1|2021-07-23|       2021-03-31|  15|
|    1|2021-07-30|       2021-03-31|  15|
|    2|2021-02-01|             null|null|
|    2|2021-04-01|       2021-03-31|  25|
|    2|2021-07-23|       2021-06-30|  40|
|    2|2021-07-30|       2021-06-30|  40|
+-----+----------+-----------------+----+
```